# Python Selenium: How to extract text from an element within an iframe?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

**The Situation**

I need to extract some text from within a div element inside of an iframe.
I have the code to switch to the iframe, but i cannot get the text from the div element.

**The Code**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
timeout = 100
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://dealers.carwow.co.uk/dealers/sign_in')

username = driver.find_element_by_id("dealer_email")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("dealer_password")

username.send_keys("email")
password.send_keys("password")

driver.find_element_by_name("commit").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("""View Report""").click()


try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(50)
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe')
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    table = driver.find_element_by_id('173d5612')
    table_text = table.get_attribute('innerHTML').text
    print(table_text)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    driver.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

**The Problem**

Currently it's failing with an error:  'str' object has no attribute 'text'
my code so far is this:

**The Root tree inside the iframe**

[image: The Root tree inside the iframe]

**The Question**

I need to get the text inside the red circle above. How can I do this? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

**Extracting the text:**

Once you have switched to the iframe, you can simply use xpath to get to the text element as below

```py
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='layout-grid']/table[@class='layout-grid']/div[@class='label-inner']").text
```

**The Error**

The error that you have received is because the method

```py
.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

returns a string, not an object and [Python Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) dont have the

```py
.text
```

attribute that a selenium object has.